# Avoid nested for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, permutation

I have a large array that I'd like to fill in. The brute-force way is to use nested for loops like this:

```
size_1 <- 26460; size_2 <- 1782; size_total <- size_1 * size_2; counter = 0

link <- array(0, dim = c(size_total, 2))

for (i in c(1:size_1)) { for (j in c(1:size_2)) { counter = counter + 1;
link[counter,1] <- i; link[counter,2] <- j }}
```

However, since I'll be calling these loops in a repetitive way in my code (later), they'll take quite a while to be run. So, to make it run faster, I decided to try another approach:

```
link <- rbind( sort( matrix( permn(1:size_1)[[1]], nrow = 1, ncol = size_total), decreasing = FALSE ), 
                array( permn(1:size_2)[[1]], dim = size_total) )
```

Just to provide perspective, for `size_1 <- 3; size_2 <- 2`, I should get `link <- rbind(c(1,1,2,2,3,3),c(1,2,1,2,1,2))`.

The second approach works when `size_1` and `size_2` are small (like the example I provided above). However, for actual sizes, I get this error: "*Error in vector("list", gamma(n + 1)) : vector size cannot be infinite*". Even if I reduce the size to, say, 50, I get this error: "*Error in vector("list", gamma(n + 1)) : vector size specified is too large*".

So, I was wondering if there are any suggestions on how I can accommodate this (avoiding the nested for loops). Any idea is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rev(expand.grid(list(seq(size_2), seq(size_1))))

  Var2 Var1
1    1    1
2    1    2
3    2    1
4    2    2
5    3    1
6    3    2
```

Comment: Thank you very much!